# Iterating over Go string to extract specific substrings

Tags: arrays, string, loops, go

I started learning Go and I want to implement some algorithm. 
I want to iterate over a string and then extract some substrings for example : `p -(40) *(GOT) +(FF)`
should return an array like this: `[p, 40, GOT, FF]`

I wrote something like this but it's vague:

```golang
import (
    "strings"

) 

func find(input string){
    var result []string
    a := strings.SplitN(input, "-(", 2);
    result[0] = a[0]
    b := strings.SplitN(a[1], ") *(", 2)
    result[1] = b[0]
    c := strings.SplitN(a[1], ") +(", 2)
    result[2] = c[0]
    d := strings.SplitN(a[1], ")", 2)
    result[3] = d[0]
}
```

Can someone please correct me or suggest something easier? Thanks!

Comment: What about a RegEx?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! kinda hard for me, I'm a noobie in programmation..

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/dRfMfZhH7-

Comment: Nice too,thanks!! you should post it on a separate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `strings.FieldsFunc`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func find(input string) []string {
    return strings.FieldsFunc(input, split)
}

func main() {
    strs := find("p -(40) *(GOT) +(FF)")
    str := strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(strs), " ", ", ", -1)
    fmt.Println(str)
}

func split(r rune) bool {
    return r == ' ' || r == '-' || r == '(' || r == ')' || r == '*' || r == '+'
}
```

output:

```
[p, 40, GOT, FF]
```

---

You may use `strings.Fields` then `strings.Trim`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(find("p -(40) *(GOT) +(FF)"))
}

func find(input string) []string {
    strs := strings.Fields(input)
    result := make([]string, 0, len(strs))

    for _, v := range strs {
        s := strings.Trim(v, "()+-*")
        if len(s) > 0 {
            result = append(result, s)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

output:

```
[p 40 GOT FF]
```

---

Also this works for your special case:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(find("p -(40) *(GOT) +(FF)"))
}

func find(input string) []string {
    strs := strings.Fields(input)
    for i := 0; i < len(strs); i++ {
        strs[i] = strings.Trim(strs[i], "()+-*")
    }
    return strs
}
```

output:

```
[p 40 GOT FF]
```

---

And if you need output like this string: `[p, 40, GOT, FF]`, try this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    strs := find("p -(40) *(GOT) +(FF)")
    str := strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(strs), " ", ", ", -1)
    fmt.Println(str)
}

func find(input string) []string {
    strs := strings.Fields(input)
    for i := 0; i < len(strs); i++ {
        strs[i] = strings.Trim(strs[i], "()+-*")
    }
    return strs
}
```

output:

```
[p, 40, GOT, FF]
```

---

Comment: I was wondering why did u choose 0 as length of the slices in result := make([]string, 0, len(strs)) ? Thanks

Comment: @jiji see detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39121360/6169399