# Go “panic: runtime error: index out of range” when the length of array is not null

Tags: arrays, string, go, compiler-errors, string-length

I am having a hard time learning how to loop through a string in Go to do some stuff (specifically, to separate words than contain vowels).

I wrote this code snippet: https://play.golang.org/p/zgDtOyq6qf.

Here is the error I’m getting when running it:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x1045a0, 0x1040a010)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x720
main.myFunc(0x114130, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3ba3)
    /tmp/sandbox960520145/main.go:19 +0x1a0
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox960520145/main.go:10 +0x40
```

I searched in this forum, and someone said that it’s due to the length of the array, but it’s not the case here. I cannot figure out how to solve this issue.
Can someone please suggest something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating a slice with length `0`, but with a maximum capacity of `4`, but at the same time you are trying to allocate already a value to the zeroth index of the slice created, which is normally empty. This is why you are receiving the `index out of range error`.

```
result := make([]string, 0, 4)
fmt.Println(len(result)) //panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

You can change this code with:

```
result := make([]string, 4)
```

which means the capacity will be the same length as the slice length.

```
fmt.Println(cap(result)) // 4
fmt.Println(len(result)) // 4
```

You can read about *arrays*, *slices* and *maps* here: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: Thanks for the aswer! Didn't know about `slices`

Answer (score 18):

First let's explain:

```golang
result := make([]string, 0, 4)
```

The [make](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) built-in function allocates and initializes an object of type `[]string` call it `Slice` of `string`

[Slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals):

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer
>   to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum
>   length of the segment).

So `result := make([]string, 0, 4)` allocates and initializes an object of type `[]string` with `length = 0` and `capacity = 4`.
And `result := make([]string, 4, 4)` allocates and initializes an object of type `[]string` with `length = 4` and `capacity = 4`, which is equal to `result := make([]string, 4)`.

Now what is the difference between `result := make([]string, 0, 4)` and `result := make([]string, 4)`:

With `result := make([]string, 0, 4)` the underlying array of this Slice is empty meaning using `result[0]` will panic: runtime error: index out of range.

With `result := make([]string, 4)` the underlying array of this Slice has 4 `string` elements, meaning using `result[0]`, `result[1]`, `result[2]`, `result[3]` is OK:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    result := make([]string, 4)
    fmt.Printf("%q, %q, %q, %q \n", result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3])
}
```

output:

```
"", "", "", ""
```

And `result := make([]string, 4)` is equal to `result := []string{"", "", "", ""}` meaning this code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    result := []string{"", "", "", ""}
    fmt.Printf("%q, %q, %q, %q \n", result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3])
}
```

output is the same as above code:

```
"", "", "", ""
```

---

> The [append](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) built-in function
>   appends elements to the end of a slice. If it has sufficient capacity,
>   the destination is resliced to accommodate the new elements. If it
>   does not, a new underlying array will be allocated. Append returns the
>   updated slice. It is therefore necessary to store the result of
>   append, often in the variable holding the slice itself:
>
> ```
> slice = append(slice, elem1, elem2)
> slice = append(slice, anotherSlice...)
> ```
>
> As a special case, it is legal to append a string to a byte slice,
>   like this:
>
> ```
> slice = append([]byte("hello "), "world"...)
> ```

---

Now in your code inside function `myFunc` after `result := make([]string, 0, 4)`, you may use `append`, like this working code ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kNb_X1hp5D)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    strs := strings.Fields("Political srt")
    fmt.Println(len(strs)) // It's not empty so why index out of range
    fmt.Println(strs, strs[0], strs[1])
    fmt.Println(strings.ContainsAny(strs[0], "eaiuo"))
    fmt.Println(myFunc("Political srt"))
}

func myFunc(input string) []string {
    strs := strings.Fields(input)
    result := make([]string, 0, 4)
    for i := 0; i < len(strs); i++ {
        if strings.ContainsAny(strs[i], "eaiu") {
            result = append(result, strs[i])
        } else {
            result = append(result, strs[i])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

---

You may simplify that code, like this working code ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4ZadHTuVZF)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(myFunc("Political srt"))
}

func myFunc(input string) []string {
    strs := strings.Fields(input)
    result := make([]string, 0, 4)
    for _, s := range strs {
        if strings.ContainsAny(s, "eaiu") {
            result = append(result, s)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: @jiji   I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the clarification about `append`. I think it's more useful in my case to do it without the append as I want to do some ordering using the same array rather than just adding at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Index out of range error is appearing because you are not initializing the `result` array with sufficient length.

In `myFunc`, you have:

```
result := make([]string, 0, 4)
```

This creates a slice of strings which has an underlying array of length 4, but since you have declared slice length to be 0, none of the elements from underlying array are accessible to the slice. So even `result[0]` is out of range of the available indices.

To fix this, simply supply a sufficiently large length parameter to `make`:

```
result := make([]string, 4, 4)
```

You can read more about how slices operate [here](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Comment: Thanks for the aswer!